# Android Picture Upload script error: How do I fix these errors?

Tags: php, android, web, upload, photo

I'm following the tutorial for sending a picture from your Android phone to a web server.  The tutorial is here:

http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/

Unfortunately, I've run across a few errors when I paste the java code into my file:

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a1);
// a1 cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

And this:

```
String ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
// The method encodeBytes(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64
```

I've read further down in the comments and they say I should replace the latter code with this:

```
String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);
```

But this still doesn't work, saying that there's an extra value in it (and removing the extra value still requires me to change a value to 'static' through Eclipse's error system.

I've read through all of the comments on the blog below and tried the remedies, and nothing seems to work.  Does anybody know the problem, or if there's a library that I'm missing that I can import (and how would I go about importing it?)

Comment: R.drawable.a1 // cannot be resolved or is not a field says that there is no file named a1 in the res/drawable folder add the image or use an  image name that is found in the res folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a1);
```

First you should have a drawable named a1(E.g. a1.png, a1.jpg, ...) in your drawable folder.

```
String ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
// The method encodeBytes(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64
```

Refer to this link, there is no such method in the `Base64` class.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

 Try this instead:

```
int flag = 0; // you can pass the default 0 = Base64.DEFAULT
String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, flag);
```